# Random Array of long

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, random

Can someone tell me why there was no error while compiling but while the program was running it gave false return. I want to create a random array of long and find the max. Thanks you so much and sorry because of my English.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
long max,dem;
//srand(time(0));
long *A=(long *)malloc(1000000*sizeof(long));
srand(time(NULL));
for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    A[i]=rand();
}
max=A[0];
for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    if(A[i]<max)
           max=A[i];
}
dem=0;
for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {if(A[i]==max) dem++;}
cout <<"\n Gia tri lon nhat:     "<<max;
cout <<"\n Tan so xuat hien:     "<<dem;
getch();
}
```

Comment: You should use new/delete in C++, not malloc/free. Also void main is not standard

Comment: You should use vectors, not new/delete in C++.

Comment: thank guys. I just want to use sth of C, that's the teacher's request. :)

Answer (score -1):

This

```
if(A[i]<max)
       max=A[i];
```

looks as though it should be

```
//     v-- here
if(A[i]>max)
       max=A[i];
```

Side note: You don't clean up the memory you allocate. At the very least, you should

```
free(A);
```

after you're done with it. Except don't do that, because handling naked memory is rarely a good idea. Instead, use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<long> A(1000000);
```

instead of

```
long *A=(long *)malloc(1000000*sizeof(long));
```

Then you'll not have to do any manual cleanup because `std::vector`'s destructor will handle the deallocation when `A` goes out of scope. `std::vector` overloads the `[]` operator to make it usable (for many intents) like a plain array, so you'll not have to change the rest of your code for that to work.

...except for one more thing:

```
void main()
```

is not standard C++; gcc and clang refuse to compile your code because of this. You should use

```
int main()
```

instead. Again, no further changes are required; there's a special exception for the `main` function that it returns `0` if no value is explicitly returned. By convention, `0` indicates successful completion to the surrounding shell; in case of an error, `main` should return a non-zero value.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that was a simple error that i couldn't see. But please help me, why the value of max doesn't  change, only number of max changes??

Comment: The `max` value changes for me nearly every time. If you get the same `dem`  value several times in a row, it's because with a million random numbers over a value range of 2 billion, the chance that the maximum number appears only once is quite high.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I got it 1 second ago. thank you for your answer. :)